# T-SQL Table Function does not return rows when used as an IN sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql

I have the following TSQL Table function that works exactly as required when used as query in its own right:

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Multi-Statement Function (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetReplacements 
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @ProductId int
)
RETURNS @AvailableReplacements TABLE 
(
    prod_id INT NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Fill the table variable with the rows for your result set
    DECLARE @tmpKey int
    DECLARE @getReplacementId cursor 
    DECLARE @replacementProductId int = 0
    DECLARE @lastReplacementProductId int = 0
    DECLARE @findAgain bit = 1
    DECLARE @done bit = 0

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @tmpProdIDs TABLE (prod_id int, prep_id int)  
        DECLARE @prod_id_test int

        INSERT INTO @tmpProdIDs (prod_id, prep_id)  

        SELECT  p.prod_id, pr.prep_id FROM Product p INNER JOIN Product_Replacement pr ON p.prod_id = pr.prep_prod_id2 WHERE pr.prep_prod_id1 = @ProductId      

        WHILE @done = 0  

            BEGIN  

                SET @done = 1    
                DECLARE ProductCursor CURSOR  

                FOR SELECT prod_id FROM @tmpProdIDs  

                    OPEN ProductCursor    
                    FETCH ProductCursor INTO @prod_id_test  

                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  

                    BEGIN  

                        INSERT INTO @tmpProdIDs (prod_id, prep_id)        
                        SELECT  p.prod_id,  pr.prep_id FROM Product p INNER JOIN Product_Replacement pr ON p.prod_id = pr.prep_prod_id2 WHERE  pr.prep_prod_id1 = @prod_id_test    

                        IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0  

                        BEGIN    
                            DELETE FROM @tmpProdIDs WHERE prod_id = @prod_id_test    
                            SET @done = 0  

                        END         

                        FETCH ProductCursor INTO @prod_id_test  

                    END  

                    CLOSE ProductCursor    
                    DEALLOCATE ProductCursor 

                END
            END

            INSERT @AvailableReplacements SELECT prep_id FROM @tmpProdIDs
    RETURN 

END
GO
```

...when executed as a basic query:

```
declare @productId int = 869725
SELECT prod_id FROM [dbo].[GetReplacements](@productId)

prod_id
91332
91333
```

....but when I try to use the function as part of a sub-query, even a very simple one, it's not returning any rows.  Can anyone shed any light as to why?

```
declare @productId int = 869725
SELECT *
FROM product p
WHERE p.prod_id IN (SELECT prod_id FROM [dbo].[GetReplacements](@productId))
```

I don't understand what's different about being in an IN sub-query that means it wouldn't work?

Comment: Did you verify the record exist for product id SELECT *
FROM product p
WHERE p.prod_id IN(91332,91333)

Comment: Well, there we go!  Just because you are working with a big database, never assume that just because something says the data should be there, that it means the data is actually there!

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try and find some examples that actually have associated data and maybe I'll get the results I am expecting! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were two issues here!

1) Make sure that the associated rows exist in the source table that the sub-query relates to (thanks Naveen Kumar)

2)  Make sure that the function is also returning the right type of ID.  In this case, it was returning an Identity column, instead of the Product Id making the sub-query return values invalid for the IN statement!